# Maven build in github continuous integration action

Tags: maven, github, dependencies, github-actions

I am using Github actions to set up a continuous integration workflow for a Maven app. The Maven app depends on some external dependencies as well as a couple other repositories that we built. In my Github action's .yaml file, I've included the line "mvn install". When I make a commit, the action begins to run the .yaml file as expected. The build mostly works, and can find external maven dependencies from maven central. However, the build cannot find the two other private repositories. These repositories are saved on the same github account as the repo. for this app.

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/<repo>/1.3/<repoName>-1.3.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.<repo>/<reponame>.core:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Here is my github/workflow action's yaml file...

```
name: Build1

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.
    - name: Build
      run: mvn install
```

Comment: This means you need to update your POM to include the github repo as a maven repo

Comment: @smac89 Can you explain how to do that?  Or point to an example of working code that does it?  I have the same question as GNG.